# Cannot access to unsecured get endpoint in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In my controller I have two endpoints where one has PreAuthorize annotation and the other does not:

```
@GetMapping
public UserResponse getUser(){
 Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
 //get and return User...
}


@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@PostMapping
public UserResponse createUser(@RequestBody UserRequestDetails userDetails){...}
```

Secured endpoint its ok, works only when I am logged and token with right role is placed in request header. But when I want access to endpoint without PreAuthorize annotation I always got status 403 forbidden. I want access to the getUser endpoint when users are logged and regardless of the possible roles they have.

Here is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
       http.csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .addFilterBefore(getAuthenticationFilter(),    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
      .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
       .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().cors();
   }
}
```

thank!

Comment: You can use  `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")` annotation for `getUser`

Comment: This could be coming from one of your custom filters. Try adding some logging to those filters to see if the request is getting rejected there.